# How to check if an object has Truthy or falsely values using the double bang operator?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I am trying to check if an object has truthy or falsely values. If an object for example has all the truthy values then i want to do something. If the object values are not truthy i.e. are falsely e.g. 0, '' and undefined I want to do something else. However, it does not work like that it always exceute the first part of the if statement. Is there anything I am doing wrong ?

```
 class Truthy {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: object;

  constructor() {
    this.a = 'a';
    this.b = 1;
    this.c = {};
  }
}

 class Falsely {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: object;

  constructor() {
    this.a = '';
    this.b = 0;
    this.c = undefined;
  }
}

  const truthy = new Truthy()
  const falsely = new Falsely()

  if (!!truthy) {
    // do something 
  } else {
    // do something else 
  }

  if (!!falsely) {
    // do something 
  } else {
    // do something else 
  }
```

Comment: Non-null objects are always truthy.  If you want to check all the properties you need to iterate over them.

Comment: Also, what do you want to do when some properties are truthy and others are falsy?

Comment: to be technically pedantic, there is no "double bang" `!!` operator — it's just two "not" `!` operators in a row.

Comment: `const allValuesAreTruthy = Object.values(obj).every(Boolean);`

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63382693/how-to-check-if-an-object-has-truthy-or-falsely-values-using-the-double-bang-ope#comment132729544_63382693) And if you can accept using the [unary plus operator (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus), then you can accomplish your goal this way: https://tsplay.dev/Nneqkw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a function that tests if each property is truthy, then combine the results one at a time.

1. Pass in the object as a param (or reference 'this' if it is a class method)
2. Get all of the keys
3. intialize boolean
4. loop through and test each one
5. return result

This is a boolean function so you can place it into the if() that you want

```js
function istruthyObject(obj){
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    let allTruthy = true;

    for(let k=0; k<keys.length;k++){
        console.log(`val: ${obj[keys[k]]} boolean: ${!!obj[keys[k]]}`);
        allTruthy = allTruthy && !!obj[keys[k]];
    }

    return allTruthy;

}

let testYes = {
    a:"hello",
    b:5,
    c: true
}

let testNo = {
    a: "hello",
    b: 5,
    c: undefined
}

console.log(`returns true: ${istruthyObject(testYes)}`);
console.log(`returns false: ${istruthyObject(testNo)}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

As [@MathHype](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4718533/mathhype) suggested it's a best practice to always check you properties.

In addition to that I added some extra conditions to check if an object A containing the object B and you need to be sure that if object B's properties has value or not.

To check that you can add extra recursion to validate that.

```
var checkObjectTruthiness = function (objectValue, isZeroPresent=false) {
  if (isZeroPresent && objectValue === 0) {
    return true;
  }
  if (!objectValue) {
    return false;
  }
  if (typeof objectValue === "string" || typeof objectValue === "number") {
    console.log(objectValue);
    if (isZeroPresent && objectValue === 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return !!objectValue;
  }
  else {
    if (Object.entries(objectValue).length) {
        var objectCheck = Object.entries(objectValue).map(function (x) {
            return checkObjectTruthiness(x[1], isZeroPresent);
        });
        return objectCheck.filter(function (x) { return x; }).length > 0;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
  }
};
console.log(checkPropertyTruthiness({a: "", b: [{b: {d: [], e: 0}, c: ""}]})) => false (isZeroPresent = false)
console.log(checkPropertyTruthiness({a: "", b: [{b: {d: [], e: 0}, c: ""}]})) => true (isZeroPresent = true)
```

Here is the demo URL for codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/js-playground-forked-ze7xun